# Show bijection of sets using calculus

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

From Stephen Abbott's Understanding Analysis Example $1.5.4$:

A little calculus (which we will not supply) shows that the function $f(x) = x/(x^2-1)$ takes the interval $(-1,1)$ onto $\mathbb {R}$ in a $1$-$1$ fashion. 
Thus $(-1,1)$ ~ $\mathbb{R}$. In fact, $(a,b)$ ~ $\mathbb {R}$ for any interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: for one-one try finding $f'(x)$ and argue monotonicity. For onto, start with $y=\dfrac{x}{x^2-1}$ and then consider a quadratic equation in $x$ or use IVT.

Comment: It doesn't reall need calculus. For any $y\in\mathbb R,$ solve $f(x)=y.$ Show that there is exactly one such $x\in(-1,1)$ for any given $y.$ There will be two roots to the quadratic equation, $$yx^2-x-y=0$$ but their product is $-1$ so exactly one root is in $(-1,1)$ unless the root is $x=\pm 1.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to proof that $f: (-1,1)\to\mathbb{R}$, $x\mapsto \frac{x}{x^2-1}$ is a bijection.

We show that $f$ is injective by calculating the derivative:

$f'(x)=\frac{x^2-1-2x^2}{(x^2-1)^2}=-\frac{x^2+1}{(x^2-1)^2}$.

It is $f'(x)<0$ for every $x\in (-1,1)$. So $f$ is monotonically decreasing and therefor injectiv.

With the intermediate value theorem, we show that $f$ is surjective.

We have $\lim_{x\to -1} f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)=-\infty$.

Since $f$ is continuous every $c\in\mathbb{R}$ gets mapped on, by the intermediate value theorem. So $f$ is surjective.